# jquery nextall remove all next elements from this

Tags: jquery

I want to remove all divs which class is form-group WHEN select changes after current select element. And here is my JS:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select").on('change', function() {
    this_value = this.value;
    this_name = $(this).attr('name');
    this_id = $(this).attr('id');

    $(this).nextAll("div[class=form-group]").andSelf().remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="card_order_form">
  <div class="container" id="card_order_form_container">
    <h2>Kart Sifarişi</h2>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="currency"><b>Valyuta</b></label>
      <select class="form-control" id="currency" name="currency">
        <option value="">-- Birini Seçin --</option>
        <option value="1">AZN</option>
        <option value="2">USD</option>
        <option value="3">EUR</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="currency_2"><b>Valyuta</b></label>
      <select class="form-control" id="currency_2" name="currency">
        <option value="">-- Birini Seçin --</option>
        <option value="1">AZN</option>
        <option value="2">USD</option>
        <option value="3">EUR</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

However it doesn't removes next divs.

Comment: Please ensure that your question is accurate when you ask it. Editing it to something completely different will only get you inaccurate answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you should apply it to `.form-group` parent

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select").on('change', function() {
    this_value = this.value;
    this_name = $(this).attr('name');
    this_id = $(this).attr('id');

    $(this).closest(".form-group").nextAll(".form-group").andSelf().remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="card_order_form">
  <div class="container" id="card_order_form_container">
    <h2>Kart Sifarişi</h2>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="currency"><b>Valyuta</b></label>
      <select class="form-control" id="currency" name="currency">
        <option value="">-- Birini Seçin --</option>
        <option value="1">AZN</option>
        <option value="2">USD</option>
        <option value="3">EUR</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="currency_2"><b>Valyuta</b></label>
      <select class="form-control" id="currency_2" name="currency">
        <option value="">-- Birini Seçin --</option>
        <option value="1">AZN</option>
        <option value="2">USD</option>
        <option value="3">EUR</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Note that it's much better to use `closest()` in this case as it stops when the first match is found (which is all that's required here). `parents()` goes all the way up the DOM and returns a collection

Answer (score 1):

The issue is due to incorrect DOM traversal logic; the `.form-group` elements are not siblings of the `select` which raised the event, hence `nextAll()` will return nothing. It's only the `andSelf()` which is doing anything.

As you're removing *all* of the `.form-group` elements, you don't need DOM traversal at all. You can simply select them directly and remove them, like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select").on('change', function() {
    this_value = this.value;
    this_name = this.name;
    this_id = this.id;

   $('.form-group').remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="card_order_form">
  <div class="container" id="card_order_form_container">
    <h2>Kart Sifarişi</h2>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="currency"><b>Valyuta</b></label>
      <select class="form-control" id="currency" name="currency">
        <option value="">-- Birini Seçin --</option>
        <option value="1">AZN</option>
        <option value="2">USD</option>
        <option value="3">EUR</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="currency_2"><b>Valyuta</b></label>
      <select class="form-control" id="currency_2" name="currency">
        <option value="">-- Birini Seçin --</option>
        <option value="1">AZN</option>
        <option value="2">USD</option>
        <option value="3">EUR</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Now that you've edited your question to this:

> I want to remove all divs which class is form-group WHEN select changes after current select element.

You instead need to first get the parent `.form-group` then use `nextAll()`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select").on('change', function() {
    this_value = this.value;
    this_name = this.name;
    this_id = this.id;

   $(this).closest('.form-group').nextAll().andSelf().remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="card_order_form">
  <div class="container" id="card_order_form_container">
    <h2>Kart Sifarişi</h2>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="currency"><b>Valyuta</b></label>
      <select class="form-control" id="currency" name="currency">
        <option value="">-- Birini Seçin --</option>
        <option value="1">AZN</option>
        <option value="2">USD</option>
        <option value="3">EUR</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="currency_2"><b>Valyuta</b></label>
      <select class="form-control" id="currency_2" name="currency">
        <option value="">-- Birini Seçin --</option>
        <option value="1">AZN</option>
        <option value="2">USD</option>
        <option value="3">EUR</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: but I need to keep pervious form-controls

Comment: Your question is literally one line which says `I want to remove all divs which class is form-group WHEN select changes.`. If that's not accurate please edit the question.

Comment: as my question is nextall, so it means all next divs

Comment: @AyxanAmiraslanli look at my answer, it does what you wanted

Answer (score 0):

Try `closest` to find the first parent `div` with form-group class like this:

Just use `$(this).closest('div.form-group').nextAll().andSelf().remove();` to find and remove **the next ones including itself**:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select").on('change', function() {
    this_value = this.value;
    this_name = $(this).attr('name');
    this_id = $(this).attr('id');

    $(this).closest('div.form-group').nextAll().andSelf().remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="card_order_form">
  <div class="container" id="card_order_form_container">
    <h2>Kart Sifarişi</h2>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="currency"><b>Valyuta</b></label>
      <select class="form-control" id="currency" name="currency">
        <option value="">-- Birini Seçin --</option>
        <option value="1">AZN</option>
        <option value="2">USD</option>
        <option value="3">EUR</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="currency_2"><b>Valyuta</b></label>
      <select class="form-control" id="currency_2" name="currency">
        <option value="">-- Birini Seçin --</option>
        <option value="1">AZN</option>
        <option value="2">USD</option>
        <option value="3">EUR</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```